# How to flat a tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree, scheme, racket

I'm trying to define a `topological-sort` function to produce all possible ordering of a graph's topological sorting:

```
(define (topological-sort graph)
  (if (null? graph)
      `()
      (map (lambda (x)
             (cons x
                   (topological-sort (reduce x graph))))
           (no-in-edge graph))))
```

only to get a tree (multiple layer list)

```
'((a
   (b
    (c
     (e
      (d (f))
      (f (d))))
    (e
     (c
      (d (f))
      (f (d)))
     (d
      (c
       (f)))))
   (e
    (b
     (c
      (d (f))
      (f (d)))
     (d
      (c (f))))
    (d
     (b
      (c
       (f)))))))
```

How could flat the tree into a list of lists?

```
a, b, c, e, f, d
a, e, b, c, f, d
a, b, e, c, f, d
a, e, d, b, c, f
a, e, b, d, c, f
a, b, e, d, c, f
a, b, c, e, d, f
a, e, b, c, d, f
a, b, e, c, d, f
```

I've tried several travel function but they all fail.

Total program:

```
(define (no-in-edge graph)
  (filter (lambda (x)
            (and (element x
                               (vertex graph))
                 (not (element x
                                    (out-vertex graph)))))
          (vertex graph)))

(define (reduce x graph)
  (if (null? graph)
      `()
      (if (eq? x (caar graph))
          (reduce x
                  (cdr graph))
          (cons (car graph)
                (reduce x (cdr graph))))))

(define (element x list)
  (if (null? list)
      #f
      (if (eq? x (car list))
          #t
          (element x (cdr list)))))

(define (vertex graph)
  (map car graph))

(define (out-vertex graph)
  (remove-duplicates (apply append
                            (map cdr graph))))

(define (top-level graph)
  (apply append (topological-sort graph)))

(define (topological-sort graph)
  (if (null? graph)
      `()
      (map (lambda (x)
             (cons x
                   (topological-sort (reduce x graph))))
           (no-in-edge graph))))

(define test-graph `((a b c e)
                     (b c)
                     (c f)
                     (e d f)
                     (d)
                     (f)))

(topological-sort test-graph)
```

Comment: Is it a list of all of the paths that lead to leaves that you want?

Comment: @AlexKnauth Exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This procedure lists all paths if called with `(list-paths (car tree) '())`:

```
(define list-paths
  (lambda (tree path)
    (if (null? (cdr tree))
        (reverse (cons (car tree) path))
        (map
         (lambda (subtree)
           (list-paths subtree (cons (car tree) path)))
          (cdr tree)))))
```

If you want to flatten the result, you can do that with a custom procedure (rather than the usual `flatten`, which returns a list of atoms):

```
(define flatten
  (lambda (ll)
    (cond ((null? ll) ll)
          ((symbol? (car ll))
           (list ll))
          (else
           (append
            (flatten (car ll))
            (flatten (cdr ll)))))))
```